# Estimate norm of solution of smallest norm to underdetermined system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have an underdetermined linear system $Ax = b$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times N}$ is a fat matrix, i.e. $N > n$, and I am interested in the solution of smallest norm,
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
x^\star := \argmin_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} \|x\|_p  \text{ such that } Ax = b. 
$$
Can I bound $\|x^\star\|_p$ based on the norm of $b$ and some properties of $A$? I am particularly interested in the case where we measure $x^\star$ in the 1-norm and $b$ in the infinity norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How simple should the properties be? You have a solution $x = (A^TA)^{\dagger}A^Tb$ which leads to $\| x \| \leq \| (A^TA)^{\dagger}A^T\| \| b \|$